# Rails Inflector classifies incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inflector

Trying to `classify` the following cuts off the last letter.

```
"ToSMS".classify
=> "ToSM"
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out why it was doing that. It treated `SMS` as a plural of `SM`. Added the following to the inflectors:

```
inflect.irregular 'SMS', 'SMS'
```

Comment: Great pointer. Just as an aside, I think a slightly cleaner approach is to define it as `uncountable` so that Inflector doesn't even try to pluralize it.

`inflect.uncountable %w( sms )`

This is the approach recommended by the reflector docs, whereas `irregular`is really for unconventional plurals, like person -> people.